# Create a list like array when echoed in php

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to echo my results from a database and have them look like an array. They don't necessarily have to be an array but look like one. i.e. When i echo my result,

i would want my final result  to look like

`[10,200,235,390,290,250,250]`

When i try the code below:

```
$query_rg = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT column FROM `table`");
$row_rg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_rg);

echo '[';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_rg)) {

   $list =  $row['column'];
   $listwithcoma = "$list,";  
   echo ltrim($listwithcoma,','); 
}
echo ']'
```

The result is :

`[10,200,235,390,290,250,250,]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. `ltrim($listwithcoma,',')` has no effect.

> **ltrim** — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning of a string

You can try a simple way with `implode`.

```
$list = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_rg)) {
   $list[] =  $row['column'];
}

echo '[' . implode(',', $list) . ']';
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `GROUP_CONCAT` in query as

```
$query_rg = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`column` SEPARATOR ', ') as data
    FROM `table`");
$row_rg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_rg);
print_r($row_rg['data']);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
$list = array(); //define a array.
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_rg)) {
  $list[] =  $row['column']; //store column value in array.
}
$lists = "[".implode(",",$list)."]";
echo $lists; //will echo your results.
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using rtrim() function instead, that too outside the loop.

```
$listwithcoma = '';
echo '[';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_rg)) {

   $list =  $row['column'];
   $listwithcoma .= "$list,";  
   // echo ltrim($listwithcoma,',');   Remove this
}

echo rtrim($listwithcoma,',');  // Add this
echo ']';
```