# How to convert an associative array into a simple array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have this:

> array(2) {   [0]=>   string(3) "NBA"   [1]=>   string(7) "MGNREGS" }

I need it as `["NBA","MGNREGS"]`

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is just the output from `var_dump()`. What exactly do you want?

Comment: They both are same. Only the second is not displaying the indexes.

Comment: Any value in array have index!

Comment: There is no difference what you have in original and what you expected. I think you confused because of `var_dump()`. BTW  if you really have an associative array then you can do:- `$new_array = array_values($original_array); echo "<pre/>";print_r($new_array);`

Comment: Yeah I have used var_dump to check it. @SougataBose. I need to print it as ["NBA","MGNREGS"]

Comment: You want `["NBA","MGNREGS"]` string to be printed? or array?

Comment: I don't need the arrays to be displayed @mishanon i need it to be as ["NBA","MGNREGS"]

Comment: as a string or array anything is ok. But string is better in my case @SougataBose

Comment: I am not sure, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996352/create-a-list-like-array-when-echoed-in-php/38996401#38996401 will help I guess for string.

Comment: No it's not working @SougataBose I need it as a simple array because i am using this for querying in the later step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For which purpose do you need the array?

If you want to use JSON data, just try to call `json_encode` on the array:

```
$array = array('NBA', 'MGNREGS');
var_dump($array);
print json_encode($array);
```

Output:

```
array(2) { 
  [0]=> string(3) "NBA"
  [1]=> string(7) "MGNREGS"
}

["NBA","MGNREGS"]
```

Comment: Of course I did. What's the problem? `$array = array('NBA', 'MGNREGS');
print json_encode($array);` will return exactly what OP asks for.

Comment: That's why I asked for the purpose of the output. I assumed JSON because the wanted output looked like JSON.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: I am actually sending a JSON object, where as i am getting it as array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "NBA" [1]=> string(7) "MGNREGS" } but i need it as ["NBA","MGNREGS"] so that i can use it for querying @Typoheads